# Converting date format of column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to change the date format of data in column, that is had been inserted in this format
`dd/mm/yyyy`. I wanna change to this format `yyyy-MM-dd` in select statement.
I've tried by this query:

```
SELECT CONVERT(nvarchar, CAST(date1 AS DATE), 23)
FROM Table1
```

On first two second I getting the result correctly then this Error appear:

> Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 
> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Comment: What is the data type of the column?

Comment: it is nvarchar(max)

Comment: A `date` is not stored in any specific format, are you storing your dates as *strings*, if so why?

Comment: *it is nvarchar(max)* A date is not a string, it is a date, however as a string it is 10 characters and does not require unicode, so the most you need is `varchar(10)`

Comment: actually it is from another person just I wanna using this format I have mention it to take out range between two date

Comment: Given your formatted string, make sure you have `set dateformat dmy` set for your connection.

Comment: How ? sorry I can't understand you .

Comment: [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-dateformat-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-dateformat-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have inserted the value as a string, then you need to convert from that format.  For the one you specify, you can try:

```
convert(date, datecol, 103)
```

Next, if the column is already a date, then your SQL Server settings might be controlling how the data is displayed.  In this case, you can add a computed column for the format you want:

```
alter table t add datecol_yyyymmdd as (convert(varchar(10), datecol, 120));
```

If the column is a string and you want to convert the format, first check to see if all the values are as you expect.  To return bad values:

```
select datecol
from t
where try_convert(date, datecol, 103) is null and datecol is not null;
```

If all are fine, then you can use:

```
update t
    set datecol = convert(varchar(10), convert(date, datecol, 103), 120);
```

You can then alter the type to be a `date`.